# Powershell's adding Integers when populating arrayList

Tags: powershell, arraylist

I have a function in Powershell which populates a list with dictionaries.

```
Function Process-XML-Audit-File-To-Controls-List($nodelist){
    #Keep an array list to track the different controls
    $control_list = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    foreach($var in $nodelist)
    {  
     $lines  = [string]($var.InnerText) -split '[\r\n]'
     $control_dict = @{}
     foreach($line in $lines){
         $line_split = $line.Trim() -split ':',2
         if($line_split.Length -eq 2){ 
             $control_dict.Add($line_split[0],$line_split[1])       
         }
     }
     $control_list.Add($control_dict)
    }
    return $control_list
}
```

Instead of receiving an ArrayList which returns only Hashtables it returns a list which has Int32 and Hashtable, where there is an Int32 in it for each hashtable element:

```
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType                                                                                  
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType                                                                                  
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType                                                                                                                                                                   
True     True     Hashtable                                System.Object                                                                                     
True     True     Hashtable                                System.Object                                                                                     
True     True     Hashtable                                System.Object
```

I'm not really sure why I have those integers in my ArrayList.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem here is that [`ArrayList.Add()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.add(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the index at which the new item was added. When you `return $control_list`, the integers representing the index locations have already been written to the pipeline

Prefix the method call with `[void]` to remove the output from `Add()`:

```
[void]$control_list.Add($control_dict)
```

Or pipe to `Out-Null`:

```
$control_list.Add($control_dict) | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just declare an empty array and then use "+=" instead of Add()?

```
$control_list = @()
$hash = [PSCustomObject]@{}
$control_list += $hash
```

Also, why do you parse the nodes as text?

Answer (score 0):

[`System.Collections.ArrayList::Add()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.arraylist.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) adds objects, not pairs of key-value, so when you do this `$control_dict.Add($line_split[0],$line_split[1])` you are adding two objects, one integer and one hashtable. If you want to use integers as keys instead, you should use a hashtable property assignment, like this:

```
$control_dict.($line_split[0]) = $line_split[1]
```

You need to wrap the `$line_split[0]` into brackets so that the proper key would be added, otherwise the value queried will be `$control_dict.$line_split` which is valid as hash tables accept objects as keys, and null as never assigned, and then getting `[0]` out of null value will net you an exception.

Comment: Except $control_dict is of type hashtable no? Just tried your method and it still yields the same