# Powershell function result anomaly

Tags: function, powershell

Can anybody help me figure out why this count is doubled when used from the function? When I check the value going into the result it only shows a count of 13, but when I check the value of the variable obtained by using the function it shows 26. Also, the first 13 mailboxes that it shows are blank (if I leave that part in, it's commented out right now). Another strange thing is that the count integer that I added should never be 0, as I put the "count++" before it writes its value, however when it is doubles itself it starts at 0. I've removed the mailbox attributes and replaced them with a counting integer to attempt to pinpoint where it goes wrong, but I can't seem to find it. Maybe my brain just isn't working right at this time of night. Script is below, and I'll paste the output that it comes back with as well. Thanks for your help, and FYI there are 13 objects in the test OU so the results that say 13 are the correct ones.

```
function Get-MailboxUsers {
  param
  (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False, ValueFromPipeline=$False, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$False, HelpMessage='Organizational Unit to get mailboxes from.')]
    [Alias('OrganizationalUnit', 'Path')]
    [String] 
    $OU,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False, ValueFromPipeline=$False, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$False, HelpMessage='Users to exclude')]
    [Alias('Hide', 'DoNotInclude')]
    [String] 
    $Exclude
  )

    $out = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;
    $count = 0;
    Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit $OU | ForEach-Object {
        $count++;
        Write-Host $count
        $FullName = $_.Name;
        $DistinguishedName = $_.DistinguishedName;
        $DeliverAndRedirect = $_.DeliverToMailboxAndForward;
        $Displayname = $_.DisplayName;
        $Email = $_.PrimarySmtpAddress;
        $ForwardingSmtp = $_.ForwardingSmtpAddress;
        $Forwarding = $_.ForwardingAddress;
        $id = $_.id;

        $NewUser = @{
            FullName = $_.Name;
            DistinguishedName = $_.DistinguishedName;
            DeliverAndRedirect = $_.DeliverToMailboxAndForward;
            Displayname = $_.DisplayName;
            Email = $_.PrimarySmtpAddress;
            ForwardingSmtp = $_.ForwardingSmtpAddress;
            Forwarding = $_.ForwardingAddress;
            Id = $_.id;
        }
        Write-Host "Adding $count to array";
        $out.Add($count);
        #$out.Add($NewUser);
        #$OutObj.Add($NewUser);



    }

    $newCount = $out.Count;
    Write-Host "Count variable is $count";
    Write-Host "Count of output object is $newCount";

    foreach($Mailbox in $out)
    {

        #Write-Host ([string]::Format("DN: {0} | FN: {1} | ID: {2}", $Mailbox.DistinguishedName, $Mailbox.FullName, $Mailbox.Id));
        Write-Host $Mailbox

    }

    return $out;


}


$Users = Get-MailboxUsers -OU "OU=Users,OU=IT,DC=contoso,DC=com"

$newCount = $Users.Count

Write-Host "Count of mailboxes is $newCount";

foreach($User in $Users)
{

    #Write-Host ([string]::Format("DN: {0} | FN: {1} | ID: {2}", $Mailbox.DistinguishedName, $Mailbox.FullName, $Mailbox.Id));
    Write-Host $User

}
```

OUTPUT

```
P:\Scripts\Dev\User Maintenance\GetMailboxes.ps1
1
Adding 1 to array
2
Adding 2 to array
3
Adding 3 to array
4
Adding 4 to array
5
Adding 5 to array
6
Adding 6 to array
7
Adding 7 to array
8
Adding 8 to array
9
Adding 9 to array
10
Adding 10 to array
11
Adding 11 to array
12
Adding 12 to array
13
Adding 13 to array
Checking output variable values inside function, they appear to be fine
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
Checking counts inside function, they appear to be fine as well.
Count variable is 13
Count of output object is 13
If everything above here is 13 then this should be working, unless I am missing something.
Count of new array is 26
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
```

Comment: There was a similar question yesterday, the solution was to redirect `Add()` output to `Out-Null` or `[void]` it. `[void]$out.Add($count);` The answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31381261/1627055).

Comment: This is expected behavior, not an anomaly. Check the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847760.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
$out = @()
$out += $count
```